# how to show my image from sanity to react app?

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I am new in recat and sanity , I made my snaity app and I have uploaded my images and other fields for page :testimonial.js" ,now i want to show my fields in react app, every field is shown except image , i use {testimonial.image} to show the image but it doesnot recongize my image path , here is my code :

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'
import 'swiper/css'
const Testimonial = ({ testimonials }) => {

    return <Swiper
        spaceBetween={20}
        slidesPerView={3}
        slidesPerGroup={4}
        className="grid max-w-screen-lg grid-cols-3 gap-x-10 gap-y-20 mt-5  select-none cursor-grab md:flex rounded-xl p-8 md:p-0 dark:bg-slate-800"
    >
        {
            testimonials.map(testimonial => <SwiperSlide
                className="border rounded-lg p-5 m:10 bg-slate-50 text-blues "
            >
                <h3 > {testimonial.rating}</h3>
                <h3 className='pt-6 md:p-8 text-center md:text-left space-y-4'> {testimonial.message} </h3>
                <img className="w-24 h-24 md:w-48 md:h-auto md:rounded-none rounded-full mx-auto "
                    src={testimonial.image}     
                    />  
                <h3 className='text-slate-900 font-bold'> {testimonial.name} </h3>
                <h3 className='text-slate-700 dark:text-slate-500' > {testimonial.job} </h3>

            </SwiperSlide>)
        }
    </Swiper>


}


export default Testimonial
```

and for index.js here is my code :

```
import Customers from "../components/index/Customers"
import React from 'react'


const Home = ({ testimonials, members }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Hero />
      <Services />
      <AboutUs />
      <ChooseUs />
      <TrustUs />
      <Statics />
      <Testimonial testimonials={testimonials} />
      <Members members={members} />
      <Blogs />
      <Collaboration />
      <Customers />

    </div>
  )
}
export default Home

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const projectId = 'q8l0xi0c'
  const dataset = 'production'

  let query = encodeURIComponent('*[_type == "testimonial"]')
  let url = `https://${projectId}.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/query/${dataset}?query=${query}`
  let response = await fetch(url)
  let testimonialsData = await response.json()
  console.log(testimonialsData)

  query = encodeURIComponent('*[_type == "members"]')
  url = `https://${projectId}.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/query/${dataset}?query=${query}`
  let response1 = await fetch(url)
  let membersData = await response1.json()

  return {
    props: {
      testimonials: testimonialsData.result,
      members: membersData.result
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: what your testimonial.image be?

Comment: @MOLLY : it is a JPG image

Comment: there's two ways to display images in react either to have them in your public folder and put the path in the src attribute or import them one by one like 
import myImage from "../images/image.jpg" and then use src= {myImage}

Comment: also if you are going to import them make sure the image or the image folder is inside the src folder because imports from outside the src folder aren't supported

Comment: @Ahmadghoneim : i have uploaded images in Sanity and I want to read images from Sanity url

Comment: add a sanity url for one of the images

Comment: @Ahmadghoneim : this the log of my json

Comment: "result": [
    {
      "_createdAt": "2022-12-28T02:59:07Z",
      "_id": "66e17955-705f-4c25-b244-a01bb6e197c9",
      "_rev": "SUjuQIB4pZbYtA4OOOZcZ4",
      "_type": "blog",
      "_updatedAt": "2022-12-28T03:50:08Z",
      "author": "Author",
      "image": {
        "_type": "image",
        "asset": {
          "_ref": "image-5be4b651a49335c844e2faadff9820fbec4f9520-450x370-jpg",
          "_type": "reference"
        }

Comment: i tried image.asset._ref , but it doesnot work

Comment: because those are not valid urls
i searched through their website and this seems helpful https://www.sanity.io/docs/image-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for the uploaded image's url specifying the following in the query to the document:

**Example:**

```
const query = `*[_type == "someType"] {
  ...rest of fields
  image {
    asset -> {
      url
    }
  }
}`
```

You can also use Sanity's [image url builder tool](https://www.sanity.io/docs/image-url#sanity-image-url). This is required for let's say, images embedded into rich text content, since you can't directly query for the url like in the example above.